# react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 Error: Minified React error #185

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, fullcalendar

hope you are doing well. for the last 4 months, my team has been working on a project and it was working fine but recently on the react-full calendar screen we are getting the above error, I know this question has been asked before but no answer was satisfactory.

I have updated all the dependencies, and have checked the code for loop holes but didn't find any...

below is my code that is currently working but when we uncomment the commented code we get the above error.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */


import React, {
  memo,
  lazy,
  useRef,
  useMemo,
  useState,
  useEffect,
  useCallback
} from 'react'

// ** Utility
import { dateFormatted } from '../../utility/Utils'

// ** Third Party Packages
import moment from 'moment'
import * as Icon from 'react-feather'
import Flatpickr from 'react-flatpickr'
import { Button, Card, CardBody, Label } from 'reactstrap'

// ** Calendar Plugins
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import ScrollGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/scrollgrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

// ** Hooks
import useMediaQuery from '@src/utility/hooks/useMediaQuery'

// ** Components
import SelectField from '@select'
import logo from '../../assets/images/ethera_logo.png'
const ViewComponent = lazy(() =>
  import('../../components/screen.components/calendar.screen/view-component')
)

// ** Store & Actions
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import {
  resetValidRooms,
  resetAddBooking,
  resetAddNewClient,
  resetUpdateBooking,
  resetClientServices,
  resetAddAppointment,
  resetCalendarEvents,
  resetEtheraLocations,
  resetCalendarClients,
  resetUpdateAppointment,
  resetProviderLocations,
  resetGetCalendarAppointment,
  resetAddAppointmentWithBooking
} from '../../redux/calendar/calendarSlice'
import {
  getCalendarOtherLocationsAction,
  getCalendarAppointmentByIdAction,
  getCalendarEtheraLocationsAction,
  getAllCalendarAppointmentsAction
} from '../../redux/calendar/calendarActions'
import Sidebar from './sidebar'
import AbsoluteSpinner from '../../components/spinner/AbsoluteSpinner'

const RolesList = [
  { text: 'Test 1', value: 1 },
  { text: 'Test 2', value: 2 },
  { text: 'Text 3', value: 3 }
]

function Calendar() {
  const now = moment()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const calendarRef = useRef(null)

  const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(max-width: 600px)')
  const largeScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1350px)')
  const extraLargeScreen = useMediaQuery('(min-width: 1500px)')

  const { success, loading } = useSelector((state) => state.calendar)
  const provider_id = useSelector((state) => state?.auth?.user?.user_id)


 // ** States
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(null)
  const [view, setView] = useState('timeGridWeek')
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null)
  // const [eventsList, setEventsList] = useState([])
  const [timePicker, setTimePicker] = useState(null)
  const [calendarApi, setCalendarApi] = useState(null)
  const [dateClicked, setDateClicked] = useState(null)
  const [appointmentObj, setAppointmentObj] = useState(null)
  const [addSidebarOpen, setAddSidebarOpen] = useState(false)

  const handleAddAppointmentSidebar = () => {
    setAddSidebarOpen(!addSidebarOpen)
  }

  // ** Referencing Calendar
  useEffect(() => {
    if (calendarApi === null) {
      setCalendarApi(calendarRef.current.getApi())
    }
  }, [calendarApi])



 // ** Locations
  useEffect(() => {
    if (provider_id) {
      dispatch(getCalendarEtheraLocationsAction({ offset: 0, limit: 1000 }))

      dispatch(
        getCalendarOtherLocationsAction({
          id: provider_id,
          offset: 0,
          limit: 100000
        })
      )
    }
  }, [provider_id])



// ** Appointments Action
  useEffect(() => {
    if (endDate) {
      // setEventsList([])
      dispatch(
        getAllCalendarAppointmentsAction({
          offset: 0,
          limit: 100,
          startDate,
          endDate,
          providerId: provider_id,
          callback: (res) => {
            let list = []
            list = res.map((row) => {
              const startTime = row?.booking
                ? `${dateFormatted(row?.booking?.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}T${
                    row?.booking?.start_time
                  }`
                : `${dateFormatted(row?.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}T${
                    row?.start_time
                  }`

              const endTime = row?.booking
                ? `${dateFormatted(row?.booking?.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}T${
                    row?.booking?.end_time
                  }`
                : `${dateFormatted(row?.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}T${
                    row?.end_time
                  }`

              const eventDate = moment(dateFormatted(row?.start_date))
              const today = moment().startOf('day')
              const isEventToday = eventDate.isSame(today, 'day')

              return {
                allDay: false,
                url: '',
                start: startTime,
                end: endTime,
                title: `${row?.clients[0]?.first_name || '--'} ${
                  row?.clients[0]?.last_name || '--'
                }`,
                extendedProps: {
                  isEventToday,
                  booking_id: row?.booking?.id,
                  appointment_id: row?.id,
                  start_time: `${row?.start_time}`,
                  end_time: `${row?.end_time}`,
                  date: `${dateFormatted(row?.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')}`,
                  img: row?.booking && logo,
                  startDateTime: startTime,
                  endDateTime: endTime,
                  status: row?.booking ? row?.booking?.status : row?.status
                }
              }
            })
            // setEventsList(list)
          }
        })
      )
    }
  }, [endDate, success])

  // ** Date Picker
  const onDateChangeHandler = (dates) => {
    calendarRef.current.getApi().gotoDate(new Date(dates[0]))
  }

  const calendarOptions = {
    navLinks: true,
    dayMaxEvents: 1,
    editable: false,
    ref: calendarRef,
    selectable: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    eventOverlap: false,
    slotMinTime: '06:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '23:30:00',
    stickyHeaderDates: true,
    initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
    // initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    stickyFooterScrollbar: true,
    schedulerLicenseKey: '0599384492-fcs-1678752810',
    // events: eventsList,
    events: [],
    plugins: [
      interactionPlugin,
      ScrollGridPlugin,
      dayGridPlugin,
      timeGridPlugin
    ],
    headerToolbar: {
      left: (() => {
        if (isMobile) {
          return 'title,prev,next'
        } else {
          return 'title,prev,next,timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
        }
      })(),
      center: (() => {
        if (isMobile) {
          return 'timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
        } else return ''
      })(),
      right: ''
    },
    eventClassNames({ event }) {
      const status = event?._def?.extendedProps?.status
      const isEventToday = event?._def?.extendedProps?.isEventToday
      const startDateTime = event?._def?.extendedProps?.startDateTime
      const endDateTime = event?._def?.extendedProps?.endDateTime

      const startMoment = moment(startDateTime, 'HH:mm:ss')
      const endMoment = moment(endDateTime, 'HH:mm:ss')
      const currentMoment = moment()

      const isCurrentTimeInRange =
        currentMoment.isSameOrAfter(startMoment) &&
        currentMoment.isBefore(endMoment)

      const colorName =
        status === 1
          ? 'active'
          : status === 2
          ? 'cancelled'
          : status === 3
          ? 'complete'
          : null

      return [`bg-${colorName}`]
    },
    datesSet: (dateInfo) => {
      const start = dateInfo.startStr.split('T')[0]
      const end = dateInfo.endStr.split('T')[0]
      setStartDate(start)
      setEndDate(end)
    },
    select(info) {
      const { start, startStr } = info ?? {}
      const timePickerOnView = view === 'timeGridWeek' || view === 'timeGridDay'
      const formattedDate = moment(startStr).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      const currentDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      const isFutureDate = startStr >= currentDate
      const timePicked = timePickerOnView
        ? [
            moment(start).format('HH:mm:ss'),
            moment(info.end).format('HH:mm:ss')
          ]
        : null

      if (isFutureDate) {
        setTimePicker(timePicked)
        setDateClicked(formattedDate)
        handleAddAppointmentSidebar()
      } else {
        console.log('selected date is in past')
      }
    },
    // dateClick(info) {
    //   const { date, dateStr } = info ?? {}
    //   const formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    //   const isFutureDate = dateStr >= moment(Date.now()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    //   console.log('isFutureDate in dateSelect : ', isFutureDate)
    //   if (isFutureDate) {
    //     setDateClicked(formattedDate)
    //     handleAddAppointmentSidebar()
    //   }
    // },
    eventClick({ event: clickedAppointment }) {
      setAppointmentObj(clickedAppointment?._def)
      handleAddAppointmentSidebar()
    },
    views: {
      timeGridDay: {
        type: 'timeGridDay',
        buttonText: 'Day',
        dayMinWidth: 270,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotLabelFormat: {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: '2-digit'
        },
        viewDidMount: (args) => {
          setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
        },
        eventContent: (arg) => {
          return <ViewComponent calendarEvent={arg?.event?._def} />
        }
      },
      timeGridWeek: {
        type: 'timeGridWeek',
        buttonText: 'Week',
        allDaySlot: false,
        duration: { weeks: 1 },
        dayMinWidth: 170,
        dayHeaderFormat: {
          weekday: 'long',
          omitCommas: true,
          day: 'numeric'
        },
        slotLabelFormat: {
          hour: 'numeric',
          minute: '2-digit',
          hourCycle: 'h12'
        },
        viewDidMount: (args) => {
          setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
        },
        eventContent: (arg) => {
          return <ViewComponent calendarEvent={arg?.event?._def} />
        }
      },
      dayGridMonth: {
        type: 'dayGridMonth',
        duration: { months: 1 },
        dayMinWidth: 165,
        buttonText: 'Month',
        viewDidMount: (args) => {
          setView(`${args?.view?.type}`)
        },
        eventContent: (arg) => {
          return <ViewComponent calendarEvent={arg?.event?._def} />
        }
      }
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(resetCalendarEvents())
      dispatch(resetEtheraLocations())
      dispatch(resetProviderLocations())
    }
  }, [])

  const handleResetCalendarModal = () => {
    setTimePicker(null)
    setDateClicked(null)
    setAppointmentObj(null)
    dispatch(resetAddBooking())
    dispatch(resetValidRooms())
    dispatch(resetAddNewClient())
    dispatch(resetUpdateBooking())
    dispatch(resetAddAppointment())
    dispatch(resetClientServices())
    dispatch(resetCalendarClients())
    dispatch(resetUpdateAppointment())
    dispatch(resetGetCalendarAppointment())
    dispatch(resetAddAppointmentWithBooking())
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar
        open={addSidebarOpen}
        handleOpen={handleAddAppointmentSidebar}
        onModalClose={() => handleResetCalendarModal()}
        appointmentSelected={appointmentObj ? appointmentObj : {}}
        onModalOpen={() => {
          if (appointmentObj?.extendedProps?.appointment_id) {
            dispatch(
              getCalendarAppointmentByIdAction({
                id: appointmentObj?.extendedProps?.appointment_id
              })
            )
          }
        }}
        date={
          appointmentObj
            ? appointmentObj?.extendedProps?.date
            : dateClicked
            ? dateClicked
            : moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        }
        timePicker={timePicker}
      />

      {loading && <AbsoluteSpinner />}

      <Card className="shadow-none bg-yellow">
        <CardBody className="px-0">
          <Label htmlFor="datePicker">
            <Icon.Calendar
              color="white"
              size={30}
              className="absolute datePicker-icon pointer"
            />
          </Label>

          <div className="calendar-selectors absolute-selectors">
            {/*<SelectField*/}
            {/*  header*/}
            {/*  wd="100%"*/}
            {/*  menuHeight="20rem"*/}
            {/*  search={false}*/}
            {/*  value={RolesList[0]}*/}
            {/*  data={RolesList}*/}
            {/*  controlMaxWidth="270px"*/}
            {/*  // onChange={(e) => {*/}
            {/*  // }}*/}
            {/*  disabled*/}
            {/*  // disabled={locationsPending}*/}
            {/*  // isLoading={locationsPending}*/}
            {/*  controlMinWidth={*/}
            {/*    extraLargeScreen ? '230px' : largeScreen ? '180px' : '100%'*/}
                {/*  }*/}
                {/*  placeholder={'Roles ...'}*/}
                {/*/>*/}

                <Button
                  disabled={loading}
                  className="button-green ml-1"
                  onClick={() => setAddSidebarOpen(!addSidebarOpen)}
                >
                  Add
                </Button>
              </div>

              <FullCalendar {...calendarOptions} />

              <Flatpickr
                id="datePicker"
                name="datePicker"
                onChange={onDateChangeHandler}
                className="form-control absolute datePicker-icon datePicker-non-visible"
                options={{
                  mode: 'single',
                  enableTime: false,
                  dateFormat: 'F j, Y'
                }}
              />
            </CardBody>
          </Card>
        </>
      )
    }

    export default memo(Calendar)
```